# Storage viewer3D.min.js locally

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I tried to save the contents viewer3D.min.js received via the autodesk api, the viewer launch failed with an error.

Is it possible to keep viewer3D.min.js locally on your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that due to the [Forge Viewer Usage Limitations](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/#usage-limitations), but you can implement a disconnected workflow by using the Web browser's cache. Please check out this blog post for details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflow

> Usage Limitations
>
> The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be
> delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.

See also the license declaration on the top of viewer3D.js and viewer3D.min.js

```js
/*!
 * LMV v7.68.0
 *
 * Copyright 2022 Autodesk, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This computer source code and related instructions and comments are the
 * unpublished confidential and proprietary information of Autodesk, Inc.
 * and are protected under Federal copyright and state trade secret law.
 * They may not be disclosed to, copied or used by any third party without
 * the prior written consent of Autodesk, Inc.
 *
 * Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:
 *
 * The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be delivered from an
 * Autodesk-hosted URL.
 */
```